# How to get specific portion of a command result?

Tags: command-line, text-processing

From the result of this command:

```
diskutil info / | grep "Free Space"
```

which is something like this:

```
Volume Free Space:        31.5 GB (31519584256 Bytes) (exactly 61561688 512-Byte-Units)
```

I want to get only

```
31.5 GB
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Excuse me, is `diskutil info` a mac os tool ?

Comment: maybe, im using mac but they are the same so it is good

Comment: Just to be clear , Mac and Ubuntu aren't quite the same.  It's just your luck that you're asking question related to text processing, which is easy enough to address. The utilities may seem the same - `sed` , `awk`, and `grep` - but they are different versions.  It's in your own interest to be asking appropriate questions on appropriate sites . Specifically, we have apple.stackexchange.com to address needs of Mac users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use awk to print out approriate information, splitting the line in two using `:` as field separator .

```
diskutil info / | awk -F':' '/Free Space/ {gsub(/\(.*/,"");  gsub(/\ /,""); print $2}'
```

Comment: Thanks it worked, although i don't completely understand this.

Answer (score 2):

Using `grep` with PCRE (`-P`):

```
diskutil info / | grep -Po 'Free Space:\s+\K[^(]+(?=\s+\()'
```

- `Free Space:\s+` matches the portion before desired output, `\K` discards the match
- `[^(]+` matches the desired output, the zero width positive lookahead pattern `(?=\s+\()` ensures that the match is followed by whitespace and `(`.

Similar logic using `sed`:

```
diskutil info / | sed -r 's/.*Free Space:\s+([^(]+)\s+\(.*/\1/'
```

**Example:**

```
% grep -Po 'Free Space:\s+\K[^(]+(?=\s+\()' <<<'Volume Free Space:        31.5 GB (31519584256 Bytes) (exactly 61561688 512-Byte-Units)'
31.5 GB

% sed -r 's/.*Free Space:\s+([^(]+)\s+\(.*/\1/' <<<'Volume Free Space:        31.5 GB (31519584256 Bytes) (exactly 61561688 512-Byte-Units)'
31.5 GB
```

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu 14.04 and above, just use `df`:

```
$ df -h --output=size /
 Size
  30G
```

To get rid of the column header:

```
$ df -h --output=size / | tail -1 
  30G
```